# Creating a replacement rest controller in spring with same name, causes bean name conflict?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

Long story short, I want to replace the existing controller in spring boot because it is not satisfactory.

Therefore I have created a new rest controller class and have started adding functionality to it. 
I want to maintain the older controller until I can delete it in the future (once the newer version has been fully implemented)

So I have effectively two classes with the same name.

**New Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v2/parts")
public class PartController implements PartsApi {
...
```

**Old Class**

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class PartController {
```

When starting the service the following error occurs:

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'partController' for bean class [controller.v2.PartController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [controller.PartController]
```

I tried using the `@Qualifier` annotation but that does not compile.

How can I have two Rest classes with the same name in the spring boot app?

Note: I am loathe to try renaming `PartController2`

Comment: you can have two classes with same names, but their corresponding beans with different names

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had faced similar issue once and it got resolved after passing explicit name in @RestController annotation, which by default takes Class name at time of autowiring. Try this :

**V2 version:**

```
@RestController("PartControllerV2")
@RequestMapping("/api/v2/parts")
public class PartController implements PartsApi {
```

**V1 version:**

```
@RepositoryRestController("PartControllerV1")
public class PartController {
```